# Как что делать, если выходит ошибка Nosuchelementexception?

Tags: python, selenium

Нужно найти сколько просмотров и время

```
driver.get("https://youla.ru/voronezh/avto-moto/shiny-diski/kumho-ecowing-es31-22550-r17-lieto-641b405929f6f2709f42e0a9")

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div[4]/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[5]/dl/dd[2]")

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div[4]/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[5]/dl/dd[3]")
```

И ещё найти сколько активных и завершённых объявлений

```
driver.get(https://youla.ru/user/5f785fc163f2106543296119/active)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div[4]/main/div/div/div/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/a')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div[4]/main/div/div/div/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/a')
```

Наверное дело в мобильной версии, на ней HTML страница изменяется.

Comment: `на ней HTML страница изменяется` — и что вы хотите услышать в ответ? неужели очевидное «так получайте актуальные элементы»?

Answer (score 0):

В мобильной версии точно такие же адреса у элементов на данной странице.

Вы берёте элемент сразу же, при том что страница динамическая и ей нужно время для того чтобы прогрузиться.
Попробуйте использовать WebDriverWait() вместо простого find_element.
В таком случае программа будет ждать появление этого элемента, а не будет говорить что данного элемента не существует.